# Need Help for showing Parse Objects into a TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I'm very unskilled so thank for your patience in advance.
I would like to display into a tableView a list of objects that i saved on Parse: each one with a name, type, and a couple of other string fields.

I've created a class like this:

```
class GlassSlides {

    var glassSlidesList = [PFObject]()

    init() {
        let query = PFQuery(className: Storyboard.ParseClassName)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (remoteObjects, error) -> Void in
            if let glassSlides = remoteObjects as? [PFObject] {
                for aGlassSlide in glassSlides {
                    self.glassSlidesList.append(aGlassSlide)
                }
              //  println(self.glassSlidesList)
            }
        }
    }
    private struct Storyboard {
        static let ParseClassName = "Vetrino"
    }

}
```

In my tableViewController I wrote:

```
class ParseTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var glassSlides = GlassSlides().glassSlidesList

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println(glassSlides)
}
```

But when I run the simulator, I get this:

> 2015-04-20 23:46:34.585 ParseStarterProject[2063:62691] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You have to call setApplicationId:clientKey: on Parse to configure Parse.'

If I put the "query lines of code" inside my tableViewController, it prints me out the desired array of objects but I'm not able to manage the cells and display data on them.

So here my question...

What's wrong with this code? ( I would like to have an array to use as the model to populate the tableView cells)

Comment: Did you try reading the exception message that the debugger gave you?  Did you try calling the method it tells you that you must call?

Comment: @nhgrif thank you for your interest.
I'm sorry that I opened a question for a problem so easy to fix but I'm at the very beginning of the path. For what I can understand, the debugger asks me to implement a method into the AppDelegate and I did it. 
Do you find my code wrong?
At the end, I just wanted to get  an array of glass slides (with name, pathology, classification etc.)

Comment: Did you read the part where it says "You have to call `setApplicationId:clientKey:` on Parse to configure Parse."?  Because the code you shared doesn't call that... and given your exception... that's step one...

Comment: You're right, but I downloaded the empty project from Parse and that method was already declared in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: ( just added my own credentials)
And i confirm you that it works if I use a sigle file with all the code in it (or at least the println() since I'm stack there  ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

In the exception, it mentions that you haven't called the function "setApplicationId".
Parse needs you api application key passed in the function to grant you access to their stuff. So call the function in your initializer to fix the issue.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution but I confirm you that I did it, in fact I'm able to save things on Parse.